# How to concatenate multiple rows, where fieldnames are duplicated?

Tags: mysql, group-by, concatenation

I am using SQL.

Here is an example of my table:
(There are actually thousands of rows like these, with varying course numbers.)

```
Course No | Meeting Day | Course Name | Instructor
123       |      M      |    English  |    Smith
123       |      W      |    English  |    Smith
123       |      F      |    English  |    Smith
```

I need to concatenate these rows into one like:

```
123 | MWF | English | Smith
```

Is this possible? :)

TIA.

Comment: What sort of table? SQL? Foxpro?

Comment: What SQL database are you using (e.g. MySQL, MS SQL, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  course_no,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT meeting_day SEPARATOR '') days,
  course_name,
  instructor
FROM
  courses
GROUP BY
  course_no, course_name, instructor
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm mostly looking to create a new table with this information though, can you help me with this?

Comment: You can create a new table from a query in MySQL by running CREATE TABLE name SELECT...